# break into ranges using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running following sql.

```
SELECT value FROM ppr_price_factor WHERE product_factor_id=3;
```

which returns values like this

```
17

25

35

45
```

I need to display my results as something like below.

```
value     value Range
17        0-17

25        18-25

35        26-35

45        36-45
```

Can I do this using sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that helps:

```
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(1 + LAG(value, 1, -1) OVER (ORDER by value)) || '-' || TO_CHAR(value) AS value_range
  FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement for the respective problem.

You can use the following sql as a reference

```
SELECT value
    ,CASE 
        WHEN value >= 0
            AND value <= 17
            THEN '0-17'
        WHEN value >= 18
            AND value <= 25
            THEN '18-25'
        WHEN value >= 26
            AND value <= 35
            THEN '26-35'
        WHEN value >= 36
            AND value <= 45
            THEN '36-45'
        ELSE '46-'
        END AS valueRange
FROM table1
```

[sql fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59e121/4)

Comment: wait a minute! Do you want to dynamically take the range based on the resultant records ?

Comment: yeah, I solved it using lag function. Your answer help me to break into dynamic ranges. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(1 + LAG(value, 1, -1) OVER (ORDER by value)) || '-' || TO_CHAR(value) AS value_range
  FROM your_table
```